# boost_log example with sinks fails to compile

Tags: c++, linux, boost, g++, boost-log

I was considering using boost_log for one project and right at the beginning I faced following problem.

Boost Log Example I found at: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_file.cpp fails to compile. Other simpler examples (without sinks) I compile without problems.

```
g++ -std=c++11 boost_log_sinks.cpp -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_log -lpthread
```

> /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccApJdsi.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   '_ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv'
>   //usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.so.1.54.0: error adding
>   symbols: DSO missing from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1
>   exit status

I am working on Ubuntu14.04 my g++ version is g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Does anybody knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 8):

You must link boost_thread manualy:

```
g++ -std=c++11 boost_log_sinks.cpp -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lpthread
```

Comment: Hi Zitsen 
I still got different error but when I added two addtional libraries than it worked. 
Thanks. 

Folowing line worked for me:
g++ -std=c++11 boost_log_sinks.cpp -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_system -lboost_log_setup

Answer (score 3):

The boost_log library uses features from other boost libraries. Unfortunately the documentation fails to indicate which ones are these libraries. So whenever you use one of these features, you need to link with the corresponding lib in which that feature is in or you get the error message:

> undefined reference to symbol

The solution I use is to loop all boost libs to search for that symbol (in your case `_ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv`.)

In Ubuntu 17.04 the boost libs are stored in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_*`

So with following script:

```
for i in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_*
do
   echo $i
   nm $i|grep _ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv
done
```

you get a list of libraries where the symbol is either used (U), e.g.:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_log.a
                 U _ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv
                 U _ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv
                 U _ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_log_setup.a
                 U _ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv
```

or defined (T), e.g.:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_thread.a
0000000000000740 T _ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv
```

This last one is the one you need. It tells that the symbol you are looking for is in the library `libboost_thread.a`. So all you have to do now is to include that lib in your link command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 boost_log_sinks.cpp -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lpthread
```

Comment: It worked after I added -lboost_log_setup and -lboost_thread to the linker.

Answer (score 0):

To compile the example https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_file.cpp, in Ubuntu I had to use a compilation with all these libraries:

```sh
$ c++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK tutorial_file.cpp \
-lboost_log_setup -lboost_log -lboost_thread -lpthread -lboost_system
```