# Can't link boost logging code

Tags: c++, linux, boost

This appears to be the same issues as this question:

[boost_log example with sinks fails to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231295/boost-log-example-with-sinks-fails-to-compile)

However, adding `-lpthread` appears to have no effect. Here is the full command line I use to compile:

> /usr/bin/c++   -g
>   topology/test/CMakeFiles/topologyTest.dir/main.cpp.o
>   topology/test/CMakeFiles/topologyTest.dir/configTests.cpp.o  -o
>   topology/test/topologyTest  -rdynamic -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup
>   -lboost_thread -lboost_program_options -lboost_serialization -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_regex -lboost_chrono -lboost_atomic -lpthread topology/lib/libtopologyLib.a topology/testLib/libtopologyTestLib.a
>   utility/testLib/libutilityTestLib.a topology/lib/libtopologyLib.a
>   -lpthread -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup -lboost_thread -lboost_program_options -lboost_serialization -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lboost_date_time -lboost_regex -lboost_chrono -lboost_atomic -lpthread expression/lib/libexpressionLib.a utility/lib/libutilityLib.a

I tried using a custom built 1.60 version of boost as well;

> /usr/bin/g++   -g
>   topology/test/CMakeFiles/topologyTest.dir/activatorTests.cpp.o
>   topology/test/CMakeFiles/topologyTest.dir/main.cpp.o
>   topology/test/CMakeFiles/topologyTest.dir/neuronTests.cpp.o
>   topology/test/CMakeFiles/topologyTest.dir/speciesTests.cpp.o
>   topology/test/CMakeFiles/topologyTest.dir/synapseTests.cpp.o  -o
>   topology/test/topologyTest  -rdynamic -lpthread
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.so
>   -lpthread topology/lib/libtopologyLib.a topology/testLib/libtopologyTestLib.a
>   utility/testLib/libutilityTestLib.a topology/lib/libtopologyLib.a
>   -lpthread /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_system.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_filesystem.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_regex.so
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono.so /usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic.so
>   -lpthread expression/lib/libexpressionLib.a utility/lib/libutilityLib.a -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib

In both cases, the error I get is:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libboost_log.so: undefined reference to
>   symbol '_ZN5boost6detail12get_tss_dataEPKv'
>   /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing
>   from command line collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I tried appending `-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` to the command without effect.

I am using `ubuntu 16.04`.

I'm at a bit of a loss. Any ideas what I'm missing / how to diagnose this?

Comment: The solution in the linked question was to add `-lboost_thread`. Does that change anything?

Comment: @SeanCline `boost_thread` is already being linked against. I tried with ubuntu's native 1.58 boost versions as well, with the same error. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Try to link with `-lboost_thread`,

**and** change `-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK` to `-DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK`.